# Mysql user defined variables and COUNT

Tags: mysql, variables, count

There is problem with mysql variables and count
The code is below :

```
SELECT @var := 2, @var := @var+2,
count(birey_dil.birey_id) as count,
@var := @var+count(birey_dil.birey_id), 
@var+1
from birey_dil
```

Here is result set:

```
+-----------+----------------+-------+----------------------------------------+--------+
| @var := 2 | @var := @var+2 | count | @var := @var+count(birey_dil.birey_id) | @var+1 |
+-----------+----------------+-------+----------------------------------------+--------+
|         2 |              4 |     8 |                                     12 |      5 |
+-----------+----------------+-------+----------------------------------------+--------+
```

I set var to 2
and then 2+2 = 4
Then I count the rows and result is 8

> @var := @var+count(birey_dil.birey_id)

Return 4+8 12 **but** @var+1 is 5
Why mysql acts like that?
The @var+1 should be 13 now and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: that's pretty horrible. what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
 
  `SELECT @var+1  FROM

  (

  SELECT @var := 2, @var := @var+2,

  count(birey_dil.birey_id) as count,

  @var := @var+count(birey_dil.birey_id),

  from birey_dil

  )x`

It seems that mysql evaluates all @var[+constant] first; that makes sense because it doesn't require database access, and only then calculates `count(birey_dil.birey_id)`. Finally it does `@var := @var+count`.